# How to tell zxing to only read my QR code and ignore all others?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

So I have the zxing barcode scanner running and in my main activity I have the onResultActivity function telling my activity to push to a new activity with a result from the scanner.

The problem is that my scanner just scans any old QR code regardless of what it is.
I need the scanner to only accept my QR code to pass a successful result and ignore all other QR codes (this should pass a toaster to say "incorrect QR code, try again").

Here's what I currently  have:

**MainActivity**

```js
...
static final int SCAN_RESULT = 1;  // The request code
...
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == SCAN_RESULT) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Action to take if result successful
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    }
```

**ScannerActivity**

```js
...
public class ScanBarcodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button mBtnClose;

    private CaptureManager capture;
    private DecoratedBarcodeView barcodeScannerView;
    private ViewfinderView viewfinderView;

    private void initViews() {
        mBtnClose = findViewById(R.id.barcode_header_close);
        barcodeScannerView = findViewById(R.id.zxing_barcode_scanner);
        viewfinderView = findViewById(R.id.zxing_viewfinder_view);
    }

    private void initListener() {
        mBtnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode);
        initViews();
        initListener();

        capture = new CaptureManager(this, barcodeScannerView);
        capture.initializeFromIntent(getIntent(), savedInstanceState);
        capture.decode();

        changeMaskColor(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        capture.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        capture.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        capture.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        capture.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return barcodeScannerView.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    
    public void changeMaskColor(View view) {

    }

}
```

EDIT: I've tried this but it's obviously not working, this is basically what I'm looking to get working. If the SCAN_RESULT = the QR_CODE then go to next activity, else pop a message saying try again.

```js
static final int SCAN_RESULT = 1;  // The request code

    String QR_CODE = "EC0111-1234567899";
    int RESULT = Integer.parseInt(QR_CODE);

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == SCAN_RESULT) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (SCAN_RESULT == RESULT) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrect QR code, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: when all but your QR Code should be "correct" than the app needs to know the content of your QR Code before scanning so it can check against it... so... why use a QR Code if the app already knows what the content is?

Comment: *I need the scanner to only accept my QR code to pass a successful result and ignore all other QR codes* - QR codes are generic, there is no "my QR code". What you can do is store "special" data in the QR code itself, so that your application can decode it and check if said data is compliant with "your QR code" structure.

Comment: I know QR codes are generic so I have generated a unique code for the QR. I just need to know how to set up the scanner to register that unique code. Currently scanning any QR code just goes directly to my result screen which is not ideal. I need to it check before passing the results. For instance the onActivityResult needs to do an if else check, how do I create the exception for that statement for the unique code that my QR creates?

Answer (score 0):

There are some approaches you can try.

1. **Encrypt information:** You can encrypt information coded in QR so that other can't read it as well as you can identify your own QR. To do so

   - Encrypt information with a key
   - Generate QR with encrypted information
   - Read and try to decrypt information. If you can decrypt than it's your QR.
2. **Develop your own QR:** It may be costly for you but it is a wonderful idea to generate your own styled QR like facebook messenger , snapchat and whatsapp etc. In that case you can't use standard ZXING library. You have to customised ZXING library or develop a new one.

   [image]
3. **Add tag to information:** You can add a unique tag(text) in your QR information. By which you can identify your QR code.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'm not really looking to create a QR as I have already done that. I'm looking at how to implement using that QR as a pass when the scan completes. The QR basically needs to be the success key to the if else after scanning otherwise it should retry the scan.

Comment: You can add a unique tag(text) in your QR information. By which you can identify your QR code.